# Convert char[] into Templated List

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, user-defined-literals

Recently I have stumbled across user defined literals, especially the templated variadic char array kinds:

```
template<char... chars>
constexpr size_t operator""_size(){
  return sizeof...(chars);
}

//Later
constexpr size_t size = "this is text"_size;
```

Is there any way to do this with a normal `constexpr` function?

Something like this:

```
template<char... chars>
constexpr size_t size(){
  return sizeof...(chars);
}

//Later
constexpr size_t size = size("this is text");
```

This would allow multiple parameters and regular syntax.

So is there any way to do do the templated variadic char array as a parameter trick to normal functions (or some way to achieve a similar effect)?

Comment: "Multiple parameters" But you can't have multiple return values. Do you intend for it to return a tuple?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack#The_sizeof..._operator

Comment: @sleeptightpupper The above link is the semantics of the `sizeof...` operator

Comment: Did the first example become legal C++ whe  I was not lookimg?  Last I heard it was blocked due to character encoding issues or somesuch.  (There was a number `""<char...>` udl, but no string).  As for the second, `template<size_t N>constexpr size_t str_size(char const(&)[N]){return N-1;}`?